# Mod Rewrite rule for images

Tags: php, regex, image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to generate various image dimensions with PHP on the fly without saving all variations.
Now I upload an image and generate various dimensions and save all those files on the server. The path to the images is as follows:

```
/20151217/124043_205037_x.jpg
```

- The first part is the folder
- The second part is the file name.
- The 3rd part is the `_x`, `_s`, `_l` flag (original,small,large etc)

I want to call the PHP script and return the image like:

```
/imageManipulationScript.php?folder=20151217&file=124043_205037&flag=x
```

So I want to make a mod_rewrite rule to call:

```
<img src="https://somecdn.com/20151217/124043_205037_x.jpg">
```

and server will run this:

```
/imageManipulationScript.php?folder=20151217&file=124043_205037&flag=x
```

I will call this img src through cdn so the image will be cached and executed only once per image/dimension.

I don't want to change the current path and structure of the images because then I'll have to change the implementation on my site

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you actually tried to write this yourself?

Comment: Yes but i am very weak in regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to tweak the 3 regex's to fit your allowed characters but something along these lines should work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)_([A-Za-z0-9-]+).jpg$ imageManipulationScript.php?folder=$1&file=$2&flag=$3 [NC]
```

Comment: With the regex you should be as specific as possible, so if the character can only be `x`, `s` or `l` then only check for `x`, `s` or `l`. The other chars in the example appear to be mostly digits. So, something like `^(\d+)/([\d_]+)_(x|s|l)\.jpg$` maybe more appropriate?